# Java: Can I use two different names in an enum to count as the same thing?

Tags: java, enums, namespaces, element, equivalent

I have an enum class with the cardinal directions(North, East, South, West):

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH,
    EAST,
    SOUTH,
    WEST;
}
```

Is there a way to be able to use multiple names for the same thing? For example something like this:

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH or N,
    EAST or E,
    SOUTH or S,
    WEST or W;
}
```

In practice what I want is to be able and sign to a variable either N or NORTH and have the two operations be exactly the same.

Example:

```
Direction direction1=new Direction.NORTH;
Direction direction2=new Direction.N;
//direction1==direction2
```

Answer (score 12):

```
public enum Direction {
  NORTH,
  EAST,
  SOUTH,
  WEST,
  ;

  // Convenience names.
  public static final Direction N = NORTH;
  public static final Direction E = EAST;
  public static final Direction S = SOUTH;
  public static final Direction W = WEST;
}
```

is legal, but `"N"` will not work with the auto-generated `valueOf` method.  I.e. `Direction.valueOf("N")` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead of returning `Direction.NORTH`.

You also cannot write `case N:`.  You have to use the full names in `switch`es whose value is a `Direction`.

Other than that, the abbreviated form should work just as well as the full version.  You can use `Direction.N` in `EnumSet`s, compare it for equality `Direction.N == Direction.NORTH`, get its `name()` (which is `"NORTH"`), `import static yourpackage.Direction.N;`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this (East and West omitted).

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH {
        @Override
        Direction getDirection() {
            return NORTH;
        }
    },
    N {
        @Override
        Direction getDirection() {
            return NORTH;
        }
    },
    SOUTH {
        @Override
        Direction getDirection() {
            return SOUTH;
        }
    },
    S {
        @Override
        Direction getDirection() {
            return SOUTH;
        }
    }   ;

    abstract Direction getDirection();
}
```

Then you could something like this

```
public void foo(Direction arg) {
  Direction d = arg.getDirection();
}
```

Then you will always be dealing with only NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST.

Comment: 1+. Haven't thought about that.

Comment: But `N == NORTH` will return false.  This means that you've always got to remember to use `getDirection()` which is cumbersome and makes your code fragile ... and probably more verbose than it was before you added `N` as an abbreviation.

Comment: @Stephen Agreed.  It's not an ideal solution, but just "A" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, maybe having a "client Enum" with variables that hold the actual "meaningful Enum"?

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH(BaseDirection.NORTH),
    N(BaseDirection.NORTH),
    EAST(BaseDirection.EAST),
    E(BaseDirection.EAST),
    SOUTH(BaseDirection.SOUTH),
    S(BaseDirection.SOUTH),
    WEST(BaseDirection.WEST),
    W(BaseDirection.WEST);

    private BaseDirection baseDirection;

    private Direction(BaseDirection baseDirection) {
        this.baseDirection = baseDirection;
    }

    public BaseDirection getBaseDirection() {
        return baseDirection;
    }           
}

public enum BaseDirection {
    NORTH,
    EAST,
    SOUTH,
    WEST;
}
```

Kinda overkill, but you can expose Direction to client code and use `getBaseDirection` for actual logic.

Comment: You'll need to do more if you want something like: N == NORTH to be true.

Comment: The problem with this is that N != NORTH.  You would need to compare direction values using `equals`, and `switch(direction){...}` would need to use both alternatives.  It kind of defeats the purpose of using enums.